# RC5 block size java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, encryption

I am trying to develop RC5 encoder/decoder in java using bouncycastle. According to Wikipedia RC5 has a variable block size (32, 64 or 128 bits). Unfortunately I have found in bouncycastle only implementation of RC5 algorithm with 64 or 128 bits block size. Does bouncycastle provides 32 bits block size also or I somehow missed it?

Comment: 32 bit block size is extremely vulnerable. That said, 128 isn't exactly fort knox either. Standard block size for a block cipher these days is 256 bits.

Comment: Thank you for reply however it doesn't give an answer to my question.

Comment: That's... why it was a comment..